# Intermittent 502 proxy error to Zope / Plone “error reading status line from remote server”

Tags: apache, plone, reverse-proxy, zope, mod-proxy

We're currently running Plone 3.3.6 on one instance of Zope with 4 threads behind Apache 2.2.  We have a number of subsites all managed from one Plone site.

I'm currently testing a new set-up running 2 Zope instances, 2 threads each, and load balanced by Apache.  We have a tool that spiders our sites to check for errors and this is reporting a number of 502 proxy errors.  It runs fine on our live sites and usually also on our test sites.

As expected we see a 502 error in the Apache access log.

```
10.10.11.1 - - [04/Feb/2012:14:34:46 +0000] "GET /family-strengthening HTTP/1.1" 502 345 "-" "Mozilla"
```

We also get an entry in the Apache error log

```
[Sat Feb 04 14:34:46 2012] [error] [client 10.10.11.1] proxy: error reading status line from remote server dev:18082
[Sat Feb 04 14:34:46 2012] [error] [client 10.10.11.1] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /family-strengthening
```

Sometimes Zope access log shows the request with 200 response but with 0 bytes served

```
./instance2-Z2.log:10.10.11.4 - Anonymous [04/Feb/2012:14:34:47 +0100] "GET /VirtualHostBase/http/test.street-children.org.uk:80/sos/soschildrensvillages_org_uk/street-children_org_uk/VirtualHostRoot/family-strengthening HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "" "Mozilla"
```

Other times the request does not show up in the Zope access log.

There are no errors in the Zope instance logs.

When I request the same pages through a browser I never receive the error.  Running our spider again results in a similar number of 502 errors but for different pages.

I think our Apache configuration for our sites is pretty standard:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy balancer://zopes>
  BalancerMember http://dev:18081
  BalancerMember http://dev:18082
</Proxy>
RewriteRule ^/(.*) balancer://zopes/VirtualHostBase/http/%{SERVER_NAME}:80/sos/soschildrensvillages_org_uk/%{ENV:SOS_PLONE_FOLDER_SHORTNAME}/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [last,proxy]
```

I don't know where to start trying to debug this so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I **thought** I'd resolved this by doing an Apache stop and then Apache start

```
apachectl stop
apachectl start
```

The problem went away on the test system only to appear on live once I switched to two Zopes there.

I had been restarting Apache gracefully.  We had also been getting errors like the following in our apache error log every time we gracefully restarted

```
[Tue Feb 07 19:41:07 2012] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(97) failed in child 411 for worker http://dev:18081
[Tue Feb 07 19:41:07 2012] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(99) failed in child 411 for worker http://dev:18082
```

I had read that these were harmless but maybe not?  They no longer appear on graceful restart after the stop / start